# Set Azure IoT Edge Module Device Wide Setting

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Is there a way to set a twin setting that is visible to all edge Modules running on a device? Rather than repeat the same setting inside each edge module's twin definition?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a reported property on edge device twin that all modules can read from.

I was also checking if you could [add Device Configurations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-automatic-device-management) to address edge modules but that looks like to be not possible as of today. You could add a feature request for that [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/907045-azure-iot-edge).